# Standard Apache (not OHS) with mod_osso for Single Signon

Tags: java, oracle, apache, single-sign-on

The **mod_osso.so** (the Apache plugin for Single Signon, provided by Oracle) is distributed with the Oracle HTTP Server (OHS), which is essentially a modified Apache. I am trying to use it on the standard Apache HTTP Server, and have not managed to get it to work.

Configuration:

- Apache 2.2.15
- OHS from the Oracle Web Tier Tools 11.1.1.2.0
- Red Hat Linux 64 bit

I have:

1. Included the module in the modules directory (copied from corresponding modules dir in OHS)
2. Included the libraries libiau.so and libclutsh.so.11.1 from Oracle Home. The absence of these libraries produced an error on starting Apache.
3. Produced a osso.conf using the ssoreg.sh tool provided with OID (the LDAP implementation of Oracle)
4. Created the required mod_osso.conf file, which I included in httpd.conf.

The error I get when starting Apache is this:

```
# /opt/apache_sso/bin/apachectl -k start
httpd: Syntax error on line 1075 of /opt/apache_sso/conf/httpd.conf: 
Syntax error on line 1 of /opt/apache_sso/conf/mod_osso.conf: 
Cannot load /opt/apache_sso/modules/mod_osso.so into server: 
/opt/apache_sso/modules/mod_osso.so: undefined symbol: _audit_authentication_request
```

My mod_osso.conf:

```
# cat /opt/apache_sso/conf/mod_osso.conf
LoadModule osso_module modules/mod_osso.so
<IfModule mod_osso.c>

    OssoIdleTimeout off
    OssoIpCheck on
    OssoConfigFile conf/osso.conf

    #Location is the URI you want to protect
    <Location /myapp>
            require valid-user
            #OHS 11g AuthType Osso
            #OHS 10g AuthType Basic
            AuthType Osso
    </Location>

</IfModule>
```

Has anyone made mod_osso work on standard Apache HTTP server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not get it to work after all. I searched all over, and found some forum posts claiming that they had got mod_osso to work with Apache, but that was on a previous OHS (and Apache) version. Even in this case, there was no guide available.